# Is there any way to switch internet network through android application?

Tags: java, android

My requirement is to validate mobile number in android through carrier.I am able to do it in case of a single sim mobile but the problem is with dual sim. Requirement is to switch mobile data and validate the mobile number through carrier.

Any help is highly appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how to off mobile data exactly but 
below code disables the wifi correctly.

Put in manifest

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"/> 

WifiManager wifiManager = 
   (WifiManager)this.context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);  // true -> enable
```

Defined function for Mobile data

```
private void setMobileConnectionEnabled(Context context, boolean enabled) {
       final ConnectivityManager mConnectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)  context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
       final Class mClass = Class.forName(mConnectivityManager.getClass().getName());
       final Field mField = mClass.getDeclaredField("mService");
       mField.setAccessible(true);
       final Object mObject = mField.get(mConnectivityManager);
       final Class mConnectivityManagerClass =  Class.forName(mObject.getClass().getName());
       final Method setMobileDataEnabledMethod = mConnectivityManagerClass.getDeclaredMethod("setMobileDataEnabled", Boolean.TYPE);
       setMobileDataEnabledMethod.setAccessible(true);

       setMobileDataEnabledMethod.invoke(mObject, enabled);
}
```

If above function not works then try to switch mobile data using Intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClassName("com.android.settings",
      "com.android.settings.Settings$DataUsageSummaryActivity");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Redirecting to data usage page.. do you know the sim card manager activity name or the way to redirect any user via intent to sim card manager page?

Answer (score 0):

You can try out this

```
public void mobiledataenable(boolean enabled) {
    try { 
        final ConnectivityManager conman = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        final Class<?> conmanClass = Class.forName(conman.getClass().getName());
        final Field iConnectivityManagerField = conmanClass.getDeclaredField("mService");
        iConnectivityManagerField.setAccessible(true);
        final Object iConnectivityManager = iConnectivityManagerField.get(conman);
        final Class<?> iConnectivityManagerClass = Class.forName(iConnectivityManager.getClass().getName());
        final Method setMobileDataEnabledMethod = iConnectivityManagerClass.getDeclaredMethod("setMobileDataEnabled", Boolean.TYPE);
        setMobileDataEnabledMethod.setAccessible(true);
        setMobileDataEnabledMethod.invoke(iConnectivityManager, enabled);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }     
}
```

Comment: Does this method switch the data from sim1 to sim2? my problem is not to enable just the mobile data but to switch from sim1 to sim2 data